# Дочерний блок больше родительский

Tags: javascript, html, css

При адаптации верстки  страницы http://k92816c2.beget.tech/ под мобильные устройства возникла проблема - при разрешении шириной 434px  Дочерний блок вылезает за родительский. Как сделать так , чтобы дочерний блок не вылезал за границы родительского?
 у[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что проблема в размере шрифта - слово "разработчика" не помещается в размеры экрана шириной менее 434px. Вы можете с помощью медиа-запроса уменьшить шрифт (а заодно и line-height), и тогда проблема решится:

```
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  header h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
}
```